# Hard mode and challenge mode trophies on same play-through in R&C:A Crack In Time?

Tags: achievements, ps3, ratchet-and-clank-a-crack-in-time

Is it possible to get the "Q-Force Champion" trophy (for completing the game on hard) during a challenge mode play-through?

I completed the game on medium difficulty, and it gave me the trophies "Q-Force Cadet" (complete game on casual) and "Q-Force Hero" (complete game on medium).

Next I set the difficulty to hard and started a challenge mode play-through. When I finished I got the "Glutton for Punishment" trophy (complete game on challenge mode), but I didn't get "Q-Force Champion" (complete game on hard). Was there a bug or can you only get the difficulty trophies on a non-challenge play-through?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/959038-ratchet-and-clank-future-a-crack-in-time/52252386) on GameFAQs, you need to play a new game on hard.